# No puedo subir mi proyecto rails a heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

[image: Codigo de eror de heroku cli]

Ese es el codigo de error que me aparece cuando hago "git push heroku master", ya he cambiado la version de ruby a 2.6.0 y la gema bundler tiene version 2.0.2 y aun así me aparece el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con

> heroku run --a {NOMBRE_DEL_PROYECTO} gem install bundler -v '2.0.2'